# Trigger a websocket connection(mutiple times) from tcp connections

Tags: go, websocket

I am trying to build an API Dashboard using websockets using golang. Due to lack of resources up there for Go or lack of my knowlege in websockets, I am posting here.

I already build an api dashboard without websockets. Now I am trying to use websockets. 
My question is more of conceptual one. **How can I trigger websocket connection (multiple times) in between a tcp connection.**

**In Detail:** 
I have two endpoints for my API. `/process` for doing some computation. And `/stats` for showing result of those computations. 
I do understand that `/stats` should be client and `/process` as a server for websockets.

Sincer Handler function for `/process` uses tcp sockets. And In between I have to send websocket messages to the client (in the begining & end of computation). So how can this be achievable?

Since, I can't conceptually do this. I am doing trial and error still no success. I guess I am missing some big chunk of information, so please do suggest some concepts or ideas to make it work. *(Programming language no barrier)*

For reference regarding those handler function for endpoints https://play.golang.org/p/EXNbj-v_Xq

Comment: I don't see where you are using TCP connections directly anywhere in your code. You also have global maps with no synchronization, which will give you undefined results even when the program doesn't crash.

Comment: @JimB The web uses tcp sockets in default, to frame the question better I used to term TCP sockets. If neccesary, please do suggest edit. I am using mongodb database to sync them, at the init of the program and at the end of execution of `processHandler()` and it's working fine. Have a look http://peeyushsrj.me:8890/stats (without websockets)

Comment: Your handlers are writing to the global ActiveRequestCount and reqLog maps, and you can't do that without synchronization. I don't know what you mean by synchronizing them in mongo, but that has nothing to do with your code having no way to prevent concurrent access in your handlers. The phrase "trigger websocket connection" is very vague; can you better describe what exactly the expected operations are supposed to be?

Comment: @JimB I misunderstood `sync`, the code won't prevent concurrent access. Well, I expect the websocket message will be sent after updation of global variables, to the `/stats` endpoint.